Why do we require Hilbert spaces describing quantum systems to have a countable orthonormal basis
It is postulated that a quantum system is (in part) represented by a separable Hilbert space. It seems that the actual (equivalent to separability) property of interest is that the Hilbert space has a countable orthonormal basis. Why is this postulated? What is wrong with an "uncountably infinite orthonormal basis"?

See the paper by Earman: "Quantum Physics in Non-Separable Hilbert Spaces"

This question is similar to: Separability axiom really necessary?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also the linked questions therein.

Sometimes it is assumed by hypothesis, but it is not strictly necessary actually, since all the formalism is valid in any cases. If the Hilbert space supports a strongly continuous irreducible unitary representation of a Lie group, then the space is separable. This happens in particular as a consequence of Stone von Neumann theorem, in non relativistic QM, when assuming that the space is an irreducible rep of the CCRs.
